# How can I write a Bash Script to display a menu, accept user input and display data?

Tags: bash

I want to write Bash Script with User Input for my assignment called "book store service". Firstly, it has option menu like "add new book name " "author name" "remove book" "update" "search" "show book list" "Exit". If I choice option 1, I've got to input new book's name. How could I write the user input and display output data when I choice "show book list" option. I've got trouble with this Assignment. Pls someone help me to clear about this, that would be really helpful and thankful to all of you.

Comment: Post the code that is giving you problems.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the `select` statement. It allows you to create a menu.

```
PS3="Please choose an option "
select option in go stay wait quit
do
    case $option in
        go) 
            echo "Going";;
        stay|wait) 
            echo "Standing by";;
        quit)
            break;;
     esac
done
```

Which would look like:

```
1) go
2) stay
3) wait
4) quit
Please choose an option
```

**Edit:**

One of your options might prompt for user input:

```
read -rp "Enter a phrase: " phrase
echo "The phrase you entered was $phrase"
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [Whiptail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) or [Dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) with which one can make graphical interfaces inside the terminal.

[Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-use-whiptail-to-write-interactive-shell-scripts/) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2099509) is a good resources on how to use whiptail.

And the answers to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/144939/multi-select-menu-in-bash-script) question is a good example of how to use Dialog

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example that shows how to read user input: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#READR

You can also use CLI arguments:

test.sh

```
echo $1
```

CLI:

```
$ ./test.sh testinput
testinput
```