# How to display a selection menu in bash using options that are stored in a text file?

Tags: bash, menu

How can I display a selection menu for a user with options I have stored on individual lines of a text file?

For example, my text file (ingestion.txt) looks like this.

```
SOUP
FTS/CTS
JDBC
NEW
```

And I want the user to see this

```
Please select an option by typing in the corresponding number

1) SOUP
2) FTS/CTS
3) JDBC
4) NEW
```

And then if they didn't type a valid number they would be prompted again.

Comment: In bash, I'd use `mapfile` to read the file into an array, then `select` to control the display and input for the menu, with `PS3` variable to hold the prompt. You should be able to search for those terms to find lots of examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033309/how-can-i-write-a-bash-script-to-display-a-menu-accept-user-input-and-display-d

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the links. I understand how to make a basic options menu and put the text file into an array, and obviously that's easily searchable, but what I don't understand is how to handle the `case` part of the menu, as this text file will be maintained outside of this script so I'll never know exactly how many options there are. I'm wanting to just set a variable equal to the string of whatever option is chosen unless 'New' is selected, in which case I'll do something else.

Comment: Why don't you make an attempt, show the code you've developed, then ask specific questions about where you're stuck?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

unset option menu ERROR      # prevent inheriting values from the shell
declare -a menu              # create an array called $menu
menu[0]=""                   # set and ignore index zero so we can count from 1

# read menu file line-by-line, save as $line
while IFS= read -r line; do
  menu[${#menu[@]}]="$line"  # push $line onto $menu[]
done < ingestion.txt

# function to show the menu
menu() {
  echo "Please select an option by typing in the corresponding number"
  echo ""
  for (( i=1; i<${#menu[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "$i) ${menu[$i]}"
  done
  echo ""
}

# initial menu
menu
read option

# loop until given a number with an associated menu item
while ! [ "$option" -gt 0 ] 2>/dev/null || [ -z "${menu[$option]}" ]; do
  echo "No such option '$option'" >&2  # output this to standard error
  menu
  read option
done

echo "You said '$option' which is '${menu[$option]}'"
```

This reads through ingestion.txt line by line, then pushes the contents of that line into the `$menu` array. `${#variable}` gives you the length of `$variable`. When given the entirety of an array (`"${array[@]}"` is akin to `"$@"`), such as `${#array[@]}`, you get the number of elements in that array. Because bash is zero-indexed, that number is the first available item you can add to, starting with zero given the newly defined (and therefore empty) array.

The `menu()` function iterates through the menu items and displays them on the screen.

We then loop until we get a valid input.  Since bash will interpret a non-number as zero, we first determine if it is actually a (natural) number, discarding any error that would come from non-numbers, then we actually ensure the index exists.  If it's not the first iteration, we complain about the invalid input given before.  Display the menu, then `read` user input into `$option`.

Upon a valid option index, the loop stops and the code then gives you back the index and its corresponding value.

Comment: The `while read` loop is slightly painful; modern Bash has `readarray` (but if you are stuck on Bash v3, you don't have that).

Comment: But more importantly, Bash has a built-in `select` command for displaying a menu and letting the user select an option.

Comment: @tripleee – Can you tell I'm a POSIX shell coder? With a few modifications, this could easily be adapted to work with /bin/sh without bashisms. In fact, I'm surprised I didn't just do it with `$@` in a function to begin with.