# what code function will help to ask for input when i try to execute a code with no previous value in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

When I choose Option 3 after opening the file it just terminates.

I was trying to use if else function inside section 3  where it ask for new values if there is none stored so that instead of terminating it will ask for values but cant seem to work it out.

```
  #!/bin/bash
while : #This program demonstrate 4 option below
do
clear
echo "Main Menu" 
echo "Select any option of your choice"
echo "[1] Show Todays date/time,Files in current directory,home 
directory,user id "
echo "[2] Enter a range  "
echo "[3] Highest and lowest of the eight random numbers "
echo "[4] Exit/Stop "
echo "==========="
echo -n "Menu choice [1-4]: "
read -r yourch #Choose option out of 4
case $yourch in 


1)      echo "Today is";date;
    echo "Your home directory is:";home;
    echo "Your path is :";PWD;       
echo  "Current Shell";uname;
echo "Your Student ID $USER ID ";
echo "Press a key...";read -r;;


2)  echo "Lower value" #Enter the lower value
read -r s1
echo "Higher value" #Enter the higher value
read -r s2
dif=$((s2-s1))
if [ $dif -ne 100 ]
then 
    echo "Range should be 100"
else #if the differnce is 100 then programe run otherwise terminates
in=$( ("$s2" - "$s1")) #formula for the range

echo "8 random numbers between $s1 and $s2 are :-"
for i in $(seq 1 8)
do
    t=$( ($RANDOM % "$in"))
    n=$( ("$t" + "$s1"))
    echo "$n" #Here we get the random numbers
done
fi

echo "Press a key..."; read -r;;


3) diff=$((s2 - s1)) #Depicts Highest and lowest numbers of the randoms
RANDOM=$$
min=9999
max=-1
for i in $(seq 8)
do
    R=$((((RANDOM%diff))+s1))
    if [[ "$R" -gt "$max" ]]
    then
        max=$R
    fi
    if [[ "$R" -lt "$min" ]]
    then
        min=$R
    fi 
done
echo "Biggest number and  smallest numbers are $max and $min" #Prints the highest and lowest numbers

echo "press a key...";read -r;;


 4)echo " THANK YOU VERY MUCH $ Good Bye"
exit 0;; #Exit command
*)echo "Opps!!! Please select choice 1,2,3,4";
echo "press a key...";read -r;;

esac
done
```

I would like for it to ask for new values if there is no previous data stored.

Comment: Try with `read`

Comment: @RAJ: I don't see any definition of s1 and s2, and I don't know what you mean by _previous code_, but if s1 and s2 are undefined, `diff`  should be zero. Why don't you pass these values by parameter?

Comment: The first part is like this:-

echo "Lower value" #Enter the lower value
 read s1
 echo "Higher value" #Enter the higher value
 read s2
 dif=$(($s2-$s1))
 if [ $dif -ne 100 ]
 then 
  echo "Range should be 100"
else #if the differnce is 100 then programe run otherwise terminates
 in=`expr $s2 - $s1` #formula for the range
 
 echo "8 random numbers between $s1 and $s2 are :-"
 for i in `seq 1 8`
 do
  t=`expr $RANDOM % $in`
  n=`expr $t + $s1`
  echo "$n" #Here we get the random numbers
 done
fi

 echo "Press any key..."; read;;

Comment: so when i run the file with this code first and then the one I am asking it works but i want it to ask for new values when i am running only the 2nd part of the code

Comment: my assignment is to make a script file where it need to generate 8 random between specific integer(diff can only be 100 between 2 integer). Also the highest and lowest random number of those integer. Also its divided into 2 option. 1 giving input for 2 integer and finding 8 random number and 2 finding highest and lowest.

Comment: Please don't expect readers to struggle with "pre" code embedded in an unreadable comment as you have done above. You have a lot of issues here. Check your code at https://shellcheck.net using `#!/bin/bash` as the first line and update your Q with a complete code and example use case. You'd do well to also update your code to take into account the comment and answer received so far. Please read [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) and [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before asking more Qs here.And, almost sure `bash` has a `$RANDOM` var built in.

Comment: confirm with `echo $RANDOM;echo $RANDOM; echo $RANDOM`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter I was able to fix a lot of code using your help. I have updated my code in here. Please have a look through it and let me know how to fix my problem please.

Comment: You might be interested in the 'select' bash control statement. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033309/8344060

Answer (score 2):

I checked your script, to see the problem. It terminates with a division by zero, because s1 and s2 initially are not set. To resolve this, you can use code like

```
if [ -z "${s1}" ] ;then
  read -p "s1 is empty, please enter a number " s1
fi
if [ -z "${s2}" ] ;then
  read -p "s2 is empty, please enter a number " s2
fi
```

-z "..." is true, if the string is empty. The shell doesn't distinguish data types and because I use the doublequotes it is safe to check for an empty string because if s1 is not set, "$s1" results in an empty string.

Btw. "$s1" is logically equivalent to "${s1}", but it is safer to use the curly braces, because there are no ambiguities this way where the variable ends. For example consider the lines:

```
year=90
echo "I like the music of the $years"
#
echo "I like the music of the ${year}s"
```

The first echo outputs "I like the music of the" unless variable "years" was set before, while  the second outputs "I like the music of the 90s". Without curly braces this would be a bit more inconvenient. Without curly braces sometimes you might run in such ambiguities, without recognizing it easily.

Comment: Sorry about that. I copied my entire code in here. Here when I tried my option 3 after  opening the file it will terminate the code. so I would like for it to ask for new values instead of terminating the file. Please help me with it.

Comment: Once you have answers to the questions you have asked in your answer, please delete them. In general answers should not contain questions - if the question is unclear, get clarifications in comments first, and then write an answer when things are clearer. This will produce answers that are clearer for future readers.